# HTML/Javascript - Button click

Tags: jquery, html, button, click

How can i use the button to make text appear when you click on it? i've tried some things and it still doesn't work, the closest goal which i reached was that when you click a button it ruins the page deleting text etc.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are working with.. It would be easier to help that way !!

Comment: See the accepted answer of this possible duplicate: [Jquery Div Hide on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092498/jquery-div-hide-on-click)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#idOfButton").on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("idOfTextContainer").innerHTML = "text you want to appear";
 }
```